# How to use CSS selectors to select everything but the table element and its contents

Tags: python, css, xpath, python-requests, python-requests-html

Hi like title says I'm trying to use CSS selectors to select all elements in div.page *except* for the contained table. I'm trying to use the `:not()` pseudo selector but `:not(table)` doesn't seem to be functioning as described.

```
from requests_html import HTML

html_string="""<html>
<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page group">
  <h2 class="level2">This is a heading</h2>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

  <div class="table">
    <table border=1>
      <tr class="row1">
        <th>th 1</th>
        <td>td 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
        <th>th 2</th>
        <td>td 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h3 class="level3">a sub heading</h3>
  <p>This is also a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph.</p>

  <div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
  <a href="https://www.blah.com" target="_blank">Blah!</a>
</div>
</body>"""

page = HTML(html=html_string)
page.find(':not(table), :not(table) *')
```

Returns the following list which clearly contains the table element and its contained elements with their text. I'm hoping to not include those.

```
[<Element 'html' >,
 <Element 'head' >,
 <Element 'title' >,
 <Element 'body' >,
 <Element 'div' class=('page', 'group')>,
 <Element 'h2' class=('level2',)>,
 <Element 'p' >,
 <Element 'div' class=('table',)>,
 <Element 'table' border='1'>,
 <Element 'tr' class=('row1',)>,
 <Element 'th' >,
 <Element 'td' >,
 <Element 'tr' class=('row2',)>,
 <Element 'th' >,
 <Element 'td' >,
 <Element 'h3' class=('level3',)>,
 <Element 'p' >,
 <Element 'p' >,
 <Element 'div' >,
 <Element 'a' href='https://www.blah.com' target='_blank'>]
```

If it's not possible with CSS selectors I'd be willing to accept an XPath solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear which elements you do want to select. You say you want the elements "in" `div.page`, but that could mean either elements which are direct children of that `div`, or elements which are descendants at a deeper level. I'm not clear as to whether you want to include the `div` element with `class='table'` which itself contains the `table`.

Anyway, I'm offering a few XPath expressions which might suit your purpose.

Here's an XPath that returns all the elements which are descendants of the "page" `div`, at any level, which aren't themselves either a `table` or have a `table` as an ancestor element.

```xml
/html/body/div[contains(@class, 'page')]
   //*
   [not(ancestor-or-self::table)]
```

It produces this result:

```
<h2 class="level2">This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div class="table">
   <table border="1">
      <tr class="row1">
         <th>th 1</th>
         <td>td 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2">
         <th>th 2</th>
         <td>td 2</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<h3 class="level3">a sub heading</h3>
<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
<a href="https://www.blah.com" target="_blank">Blah!</a>
```

NB it returns the `div` which *contains* the `table`, but it doesn't return the `table` directly.

Here's another one which returns the same set of elements, but also excluding the ones which *contain* the table as a descendant. That excludes the `div.table`.

```xml
/html/body/div[contains(@class, 'page')]
   //*
   [not(ancestor-or-self::table)]
   [not(descendant-or-self::table)]
```

Producing this result:

```
<h2 class="level2">This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h3 class="level3">a sub heading</h3>
<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
<a href="https://www.blah.com" target="_blank">Blah!</a>
```

Here's one which returns the *children* of `div.page`, except those that either contain, or are contained by, a `table`.

```xml
/html/body/div[contains(@class, 'page')]
   /*
   [not(ancestor-or-self::table)]
   [not(descendant-or-self::table)]
```

When evaluated on the sample document you provided in your question, it produces the same result as the previous expression, but it would have a different effect for pages which had more deeply nested elements, e.g. `div` elements within `div` elements, etc. It would not duplicate elements which were nested.

I'm guessing, of course, because I don't know exactly the purpose of the selection you're making, but I suspect this last expression is most likely the best.

Comment: Apologies for not being more clear. Your last XPath solution worked! But I have a confession: the page I'm actually trying to grab is from [here](http://docs.daz3d.com/doku.php/public/read_me/index/80093/start)—the HTML in the question was a stripped down test case. Unfortunately, the solution didn't exactly transfer to the full page of data but you did get me looking into XPath to modify your solution which I did find and looks like this:

`page.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "page")]/div[@class="level1"]/* [not(descendant-or-self::table)]')])`